# How can I take down an awning?

Tags: patio, winterizing

I need to take down this awning for the winter. It's 20ft x 10ft. The 20ft side (the side on the right in the picture, adjacent to the house) is wrapped around a 20ft-long steel beam. The three other sides are held in place by a long cord  woven through eyelets.

[image: awning]

How do I take down such an awning? I'm guessing that the side with the beam should be detached first and unrolled down gradually while the cords are undone slowly. Is this about right? I'm also guessing that this is a task for two folks capable of carrying a rather hefty load, and it should not be attempted solo. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That photo is not very helpful in identifying how the awning is attached to the house. In general, there should be brackets of some type, which grab hold of a metal rod that's within a pocket of the awning. Once you've figured out how to free the top of the awning from the house, you'll have to remove the ropes that tie the awning to the support structure. Once the cover is free, you can roll it, or fold it up.

It shouldn't weigh too much, as it's just a sheet of canvas.  I usually take mine down, and put it up by myself. So if you're able bodied, you should have no problem. If you're not, you might want a hand getting it down.

Comment: Your guess is exactly right. There is a metal rod within a pocket, and there are brackets keeping the rod in place. It's trivial to undo the brackets, but I'm less sure how–after undoing the brackets and the rope–to ensure I will not find the entire thing tumbling down on me. There is no way to remove the metal rod before undoing the bracket.

Comment: You could undo the ropes, and let the awning hang down. Then remove the brackets (removing the outer two last), and carefully lower the awning down.  The metal rod is likely a small diameter metal pipe, which shouldn't weigh much.